# Creating the libwatoolkitios.a file is not clear to me - why can't I simply download it?

Tags: ios, windows, azure

I was playing around now since a while with the windows azure ios toolkit. However - as I am a newbie to iOS coding - I still do not understand the process for creating the libwatoolkitios.a. Also as I am not sure whethere this is still the up to date way in accessing windows azure within iPhone applications.

Can someone maybe support me in this topic and let me know which steps I have to take to successfully implement this static library in my iOS app?